# JQuery .clone() a select list and ladbel, loading label from an array

Tags: jquery, forms, clone, label

I am looking to clone two form elements multiple times.  A select box and it's label, however each time I clone element I would like to provide the label text from a array.  Am I approaching this the correct way or should I try something different

```
<a href="#" onClick="createElement(5)">CLICK ME</a>
    <div id="selectBox1" class="cloned">
        <label>LABEL</label>
        <select name="name1" id="name1">
            <option>ONE</option>
            <option>TWO</option>
            <option>THREE</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</a>
```

```
function createElement(numElements) {
    //alert(numElements);

    //LABEL ARRAY
    var labels = [
        'Market',
        'Store',
        'Report Level',
        'Start Date',
        'End Date'];


    for (i = 0; i < numElements-1; i++) {                    
        var num = $('.cloned').length;//HOW MANY WE HAVE              
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1); //NUMBER OF ELEMENT BEING ADDED

        //LABEL
        //var newLabel = $('#selectLabel' + num).clone().attr('id', 'selectLabel' + newNum);//CLONE LABEL
        //newLabel.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum);//UPDATE NAME/ID

        //SELECTBOX
        var newElem = $('#selectBox' + num).clone().attr('id', 'selectBox' + newNum);//CLONE SELECTBOX
        newElem.children(':first').attr('id', 'name' + newNum).attr('name', 'name' + newNum);//UPDATE NAME/ID

        //$('#selectLabel' + num).after(newLabel);//INSERT THE NEW LABEL
        $('#selectBox' + num).after(newElem);//INSERT THE NEW ELEMENT
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you clone `#selectBox1` it will automatically clone the child elements as well.

Comment: Where are the `<script>` tags for your js code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    //LABEL ARRAY
    var labels = [
        'Market',
        'Store',
        'Report Level',
        'Start Date',
        'End Date'
    ];
    var count = labels.length;

    $('#selectBox1').bind('click', function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var clones = $();
        var num = $('.cloned').length;

        $.each(labels, function(index, label) {
            var clone = self.clone();

            clone.attr({id: 'selectBox'+(++num)'});
            clone.find('label').attr({
                id: 'name'+num,
                name: 'name'+num
            }).text(label);

            clones = clones.add(clone[0]);
        });

        $('.cloned:last').after(clones);
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh, I just saw that I messed up the label and select updates but I think you get the point.

Comment: Yes, no worries.  I am cloning these element depending on what you select from the left navigation, can i change the "var clone = self.clone();" to each element in the array?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. You need to clone the parent div and it shouldn't make any difference which one you pick, as long as they contain the elements you want, right?

Comment: Oh, and btw. I'd rethink your approach. You do know that multiple select elements can form an array (e.g. `name="name[]"`)? This way you wouldn't have to fiddle with the iterating numbers in the back-end.

Comment: I may need to rethink.  What I have is multiple navigation elements that will display between one and twenty drop down's (on the right) depending on which nav item you select. I was going to hide the cloned element only displaying what I pass from the array.